# run shell script on files in multiple directory in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script which needs to be run on paired files (e.g. `file1` and `file2`). For each pair, there should be 5 output files generated in the current directory. How can I run a shell script on multiple paired files in different directories?

To be more specific, the structure looks like the following:

```
pair1: /x/y/z/1/file1 and x/y/z/1/file2
pair2: /x/y/z/2/file1 and x/y/z/2/file2
```

I want to run the same shell script on multiple pairs like these two. The output needs to be saved in the current directory, e.g. `/x/y/z/1/` for `pair1`.

Comment: As it stands there's not sufficient information to understand what you're asking. Can you please be more specific, give an example of the directory structure, describe what constitutes a "pair" other than saying you have file1 and file2?

Comment: The structure will be look like---pair1: "/x/y/z/1/file1" and "x/y/z/1/file2";   pair2:"x/y/z/2/file1" and "x/y/z/2/file2". I want to run the same shell script on multiple pairs like these two. The output need to be save at the current directory, for the output of pair1, it will be /x/y/z/1/

Comment: Great ... now edit your question and make it readable ;}  And also let us know whether it's guaranteed that these pairs are always complete, or whether error-checking is required.

Comment: Run something for every directory that is under some given directory: `find /your/top/dir -type d -exec yourscript {} \;`  The name of each thing (directory) found will be passed as an argument to _yourscript_ which can use it to build paths or `cd $1` to change to that directory.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen! The script is a shell script. How should I refer the input file names in it? Does it mean all the file names should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Run the script as:

```
myscript /x/y/z/1/file1 /x/y/z/1/file2 /x/y/z/2/file1 /x/y/z/2/file2
```

The script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

create_five_files_with_pair() {
  cp $1 outfile1
  cp $2 outfile2
  cat $1 $2 > outfile3
  cat $2 $1 > outfile4
  paste $1 $2 > outfile5
}

while test $# -gt 1
do
  cd $(dirname $1)
  create_five_files_with_pair $(basename $1) $(basename $2)
  shift
  shift
done
```

Comment: Hi mouviciel! I appreciate your help but I barely understand the script. What's the purpose of "create_five_files_with_pair"? Where should I include my own shell scripts?

Comment: `create_five_files_with_pair` is only a placeholder for your computations.